# Jump to a specific viewcontroller xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have 6 view controllers embed in a navigation controller. Let says the user open the app and used the view controller 1 and 2 and then closed the app. How can I make him jump to a specific view controller once he reuses the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add some variable on the userDefault for check the status of the user, and in the scendedelagate add some validation for move the application on the view controller that you want.

for instance.

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        if "your variable UserDefaults variable saved" {
// setupViewController
            window?.rootViewController = SomeViewController()
        }else{
            window?.rootViewController = NormalViewController()
        }
    }
```

In the code of above I setup different launch screen depends of the userDefault that I saved, setup the rootViewController.